# redirect user from one layout to another in same function - java thymeleaf spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Hello all I am working on java using thymeleaf.

this is my method to load dashbaord page:

```
@Layout("layouts/default.html")
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Dashboard() {
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    if (session.getAttribute("loginStatus") != "1") {
        mav = new ModelAndView("index.html");
    } else {
        mav = new ModelAndView("dashbaord.html");
    }
    return mav;
}
```

In above method if user is logged in it will load `dashbaord.html` page which is designed to render `layouts/default.html` BUT if user is not logged in and tries to load dashboard page, it should go to `index.html`

BUT in my case `index` page doesn't contain any layout and when user tries to load dashboard page without login it gives me rendering error for `layouts/default.html` because index page is not designed to render anything from layouts. it is a separate page with no layout.

I have followed [this](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/thymeleaf-template-layouts-in-spring.html) configuration for my layouts rendering.

**Index Page RequestHandler:**

```
@Layout(Layout.NONE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    mav = new ModelAndView("index.html");
    return mav;
}
```

Any idea, how can I set the layout conditionally ?

Comment: maybe you should redirect the request from `/dashboard` to `/` if user is not logged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@Layout("layouts/default.html")
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Dashboard() {
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    if (session.getAttribute("loginStatus") != "1") {
        return "redirect:/";
    } else {
        return "dashbaord.html";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it helped. I have done this using ModelAndView, posting my answer below

Answer (score 0):

**Correct answer :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Dashboard(HttpSession session) {

    ModelAndView mav = null;
    mav = new ModelAndView("dashbaord.html");
    if (session.getAttribute("loginStatus") != "1") {
        mav=new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    } else {
        mav=new ModelAndView("dashbaord.html");
    }
    return mav;
}
```